# karate does not match xml with namespaces

Tags: karate

I have two xml messages with namespaces which are essentially the same xml but match says they are not same.

Please look at the feature below.
xmlString1 and xmlString2 are essentially same xmls. Only the namespace prefix is different. I am not sure if match matches xml equality?
Is there a way I can achieve xml match with namespaces?

```
Feature: Test xml match
  Scenario: test xml match with namespaces
    * def xmlString1 =
    """
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:b="anotherUri">
      <soapenv:Header/>
      <soapenv:Body>
        <b:validateEmailAddressRequest>
          <request>
           <email>some@domain.com</email>
          </request>
         </b:validateEmailAddressRequest>
        </soapenv:Body>
     </soapenv:Envelope>
    """

    * def xmlString2 =
    """
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:a="anotherUri">
      <soapenv:Header/>
      <soapenv:Body>
        <a:validateEmailAddressRequest>
          <request>
           <email>some@domain.com</email>
          </request>
         </a:validateEmailAddressRequest>
        </soapenv:Body>
     </soapenv:Envelope>
    """

    * xml xml1  = xmlString1
    * xml xml2  = xmlString2

    * match xml1 == xml2

16:49:04.363 [main] ERROR com.intuit.karate - assertion failed: path: /soapenv:Envelope/_/soapenv:Body, actual: '<soapenv:Body><b:validateEmailAddressRequest><request><email>some@domain.com</email></request></b:validateEmailAddressRequest></soapenv:Body>', expected: '<soapenv:Body><a:validateEmailAddressRequest><request><email>some@domain.com</email></request></a:validateEmailAddressRequest></soapenv:Body>', reason: all key-values did not match, expected has un-matched keys: [a:validateEmailAddressRequest]
xml-match.feature:34 - path: /soapenv:Envelope/_/soapenv:Body, actual: '<soapenv:Body><b:validateEmailAddressRequest><request><email>some@domain.com</email></request></b:validateEmailAddressRequest></soapenv:Body>', expected: '<soapenv:Body><a:validateEmailAddressRequest><request><email>some@domain.com</email></request></a:validateEmailAddressRequest></soapenv:Body>', reason: all key-values did not match, expected has un-matched keys: [a:validateEmailAddressRequest]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are welcome to contribute a fix for this. Meanwhile you can do this. Note that you don't need to convert to xml, `def xml1` is sufficient even if you use the triple-quote multi-line form. You may be confused with [`text`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#text).

```
* xmlstring xml2 = xml2
* xml xml2 = xml2.replaceAll('(</?)a:', '$1b:').replace('xmlns:a', 'xmlns:b')
* match xml1 == xml2
```

Comment: Thank u for response. Just a thought - I believe karate internally convert xml to json map and than try to match it. one (not nice) way is to remove also the namespace prefixes than match would work but still it won't be matching xml equality. this would still be usable and sufficient soltulation.

Comment: I thought of changing match itself for xml comparison so we wouldn't need apply workaround for each match. Moreover namespaces prefix is unknown until you receive the response from a server. what do you think?

Comment: @Prashant you are the first in 2.5 years to request this. please contribute a fix if you can - or just use the workaround. IMO this is a very rare requirement

Comment: I see. One more thing match doesn't match #boolean and #number in xml. is this indented behaviour ?

Comment: @Prashant yes - in XML everything is a string unless you have a schema, and we keep it simple. this should not block you from doing assertions