# Karate throwing SAXParseException; 0; Content is not allowed in prolog. when parsing XML

Tags: javascript, xml, karate

I am trying to parse a XML that looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Val1 xmlns:com="somevalue" xmlns:pol="somevalue" xmlns="somevalue">
    <msgResult xmlns="">
        <com:msgcONG>Congrats</com:msgcONG>
        <com:msgcONGSour>ResultWeb</com:msgcONG>
```

I try to do:
print response /Val1/msgResult/msgcONG

However, it keeps throwing this error

```
SAXParseException; 0; Content is not allowed in prolog. when parsing XML
```

Anyway to go around this problem with Karate?

I have tried to replace the Strings that might be causing issues:

```
* xml response = response.replace("\r","").replace("\n", "").replace("utf-16","utf-8").replaceAll("xmlns:xsi[^>]*", "")
```

Now when I do:

```
* print $response/Val1/msgResult/msgcONG
```

I am getting : `ReferenceError: "$response" is not defined`

Also tried: `* match response contains '<com:msgcONG>Congrats</com:msgcONG>`

Error:
match failed: CONTAINS
/ | data types don't match (XML:STRING)

Comment: also refer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71327601/143475

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing more research, I decided to parse the response through Java.
In my .feature file I'm calling my function doing:

```
* xml response = cleanUpXml(response)
```

And this is what the Java function looks like:
It get rid of all the invalid character but also the namespaces making it easier to parse the XML through karate

```
   public static String cleanUpXml(Object oldxml) {
        try {
             String xml = oldxml.toString()
             TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
             Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
             transformer.setOutputProperty( OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml" );
             transformer.setOutputProperty( OutputKeys.INDENT, "false" );
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
            Document xmlDoc = builder.parse(inputSource);
            Node root = xmlDoc.getDocumentElement();
            NodeList rootchildren = root.getChildNodes();
            Element newroot = xmlDoc.createElement(root.getNodeName());
            for (int i = 0; i < rootchildren.getLength(); i++) {
                newroot.appendChild(rootchildren.item(i).cloneNode(true));
            }
            xmlDoc.replaceChild(newroot, root);
            DOMSource requestXMLSource = new DOMSource( xmlDoc.getDocumentElement() );
            StringWriter requestXMLStringWriter = new StringWriter();
            StreamResult requestXMLStreamResult = new StreamResult( requestXMLStringWriter );            
            transformer.transform( requestXMLSource, requestXMLStreamResult );
            String modifiedRequestXML = requestXMLStringWriter.toString();

            return modifiedRequestXML;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Could not parse message as xml: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to submit an issue, if there is a bug in XML handling.

As a workaround, you can use text as described here, and do string replace operations to move forward: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57062885/143475

Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57825429/143475 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/53682733/143475

Comment: I've tried the string replacement, after some debugging I found my raw xml had '\r\n'   - I edited my post with what I've tried, still unsuccesful

Comment: Please see my comment for the solution - I've raised an issue on GIT HUB so it could be implemented as part of Karate to help anyone else !